# Python : Need Help About dataset

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory

What i should do after this code
"from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive') "
To download my dataset in google colabe and testing it .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu16i.png)

This is the result when i runing this code .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the data into a dataframe you could do something like this after you have successfully mounted the drive:

```
import pandas as pd
file = '/content/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df.head
```

Note that I am using the sample data. You will need to update the path after you have uploaded your data (see left side "Files" pane).